# How can I observe Array field in Ember.Object?

Tags: ember.js

I've this code (http://jsfiddle.net/stephane_klein/gyHmS/2/) :

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Item = Ember.Object.extend({
    title: null,
    parent: null
});

App.MyList = Ember.Object.extend({
    title: null,
    content: [],
    changed: function() {
        console.log('here');
    }.observes('content')
});

App.list = App.MyList.create({
    title: "foobar",
    content: [
        App.Item.create({
            item: "item1"
        }),
        App.Item.create({
            item: "item2"
        })
    ]
});
console.log(App.list.content);

App.list.content.pushObject(
    App.Item.create({
        item: "item3"
    })
);
console.log(App.list.content);
```

Why "console.log('here')" is never called ?

I want set App.Item.parent when App.Item is inserted in App.MyList. I don't know how to observe App.MyList.content field.

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,
Stephane

Answer (score 6):

You're not changing the content property, you're just pushing an object in there.
You have two solutions:

- You can observe each item of the content (using `.observes('content.@each')`), but take attention, the method could be called several times
- Or manually notify that this property has changed (using `this.notifyPropertyChange('content')`)

Here is the first solution: [jsfiddle using @each](http://jsfiddle.net/PjUhM/)

And here is the second solution: [jsfiddle using notifyPropertyChange](http://jsfiddle.net/sKg9v/)

You also have to notice you should not use directly `App.list.content` but `App.list.get('content')` instead. Take a look at [this article written by Roy Daniels](http://ud3323.github.com/2012/02/15/ember-controllers-and-the-runloop.html) if you want more information.

**EDIT**

Please notice the use of `@each` has slightly changed. The [Ember.Array#@each documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#property__each) says:

> Returns a special object that can be used to observe individual
>   properties on the array. Just get an equivalent property on this
>   object and it will return an enumerable that maps automatically to the
>   named key on the member objects.
>
> If you merely want to watch for any items being added or removed to
>   the array, use the [] property instead of @each.

Lets see that with an example:

```
App.Post = Ember.Object.extend({
  createdAt: null
});

App.Blog = Ember.Object.extend({
  posts: null,

  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.set 'posts', [];
  },

  newerPost: function() {
    return this.get('posts').sortBy('createdAt').get('firstObject');
  }.property('posts.@each.createdAt'),

  postsCount: function() {
    return this.get('posts.length');
  }.property('posts.[]')
});
```

`newerPost` needs to observes a particular property of each `posts`, whereas `postsCount` just needs to know when the `posts` array changes.

Comment: 'content.@each' is working if the content is a "simple" object... but how to do the same if the object is a "complex" object (Person: firstName, lastName) ??? it seems that .observes('content.firstName.@each') is not working...

Comment: `content.@each` is working only if the content is an array (see the source code: http://goo.gl/Nxuvq). You don't need it for non-array objects, you can just use `.observes('content.firstName')` for observing the firstName property of the content